kinit: Pre-authentication failed: Permission denied while getting initial credentials
While struggling to standup a Linux hosted SQL Server container connected to Active Directory, I started to get errors from kinit when refreshing my krb5 tickets

kinit: Pre-authentication failed: Permission denied while getting initial credentials


This error was due to a bad /etc/krb5.conf.
It had been working, but I had made changes to the environment (made a new Domain Controller with a new IP) and the krb5.conf was out of date
Fixing /etc/krb5.conf was not enough, recreating the ticket was required
kdestroy
kinit myuser@CONTOSO.COM # Use correct username here

